# How to make network interface usable

Tags: networking, unix, routing

I'm trying to migrate a server from macOS to a NAS (synology) and I'm having some problems porting a `route` command.

On macOS I used this command to make the VPN route usable:

`/sbin/route add -ifscope "$dev" default "$route_vpn_gateway"`

but on Synology the route command has no `ifscope` option. I'm a bit lost on how the replicate the functionality.

The end result should be that the default routes do not use the VPN but if you specify the `tun0` iface you should use the VPN, this allows my to choose which apps that use VPN.

Comment: The ifscope appears to be mac specific and looks at an interface - the Linux equivalent (and last I looked Synology ran Linux) does not have this.  

In order to do this with Linux you need to do source based/policy routing.   (I've not advised how to, because I don't have a synology box to find out what it wants, but its comparatively complex - https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/ is the first tutorial I googled.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by manually adding a route to the `tun0-table` using the following command:

`/sbin/ip route add default via "$route_vpn_gateway" dev "$dev" table "$dev-table"`

That command is present in my `route-up` script along with a `route-nopull` in my openvpn config.